# PHPUnit: how to test that a method hasn't been called "yet", but will be called later in test case?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to test that a method is not called at some point in the test case, but is expected to be called later. Here's an example test:

```
<?php

class B {
    public function doSomething() {}
}

class A {
    private $b;
    private $buffer = array();

    public function __construct($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function x($val) {
        $this->buffer[] = $val;

        if (count($this->buffer) == 3) {
            $this->b->doSomething();
        }
    }
}

class XTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testB() {
        $b = $this->getMock('B');
        $a = new A($b);

        $a->x(1);
        $a->x(2);

        // doSomething is not called YET
        $b->expects($this->never())->method('doSomething');

//      $b->expects($this->at(0))->method('doSomething'); // ??????

        $a->x(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems another test case method

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I don't think it is necessary to do this. Plus, I don't see a way to check the previous calls, either. I'd rather check for the parameters `flush()` is executed with:

```
$b = $this->getMock('B');
$b->expects($this->exactly(1))
    ->method('flush')
    ->with(array(1, 2, 3));

$a = new A($b);

$a->x(1);
$a->x(2);
$a->x(3);
```

Usually, you'd need to check for previous methods if other mock methods are called, which you can do by telling the mocked methods exactly when they are supposed to call with `at()`.

Comment: Ok, so if, for example, `flush` would be called not with the contents of a buffer, but with something different - e.g. "once a buffer has 3 items, ping external service", how would I test that service is not pinged until there are exactly 3 items?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I quite understand you here. You ping the external service with `flush` right? In this case you already test it. PHPUnit will throw an error as soon as something different from this exact array `[1, 2, 3]` is used as parameter 0 or the method is called more than one time. It is the most strict way to test how A triggers `flush`

Comment: I've edited the code in the original question to illustrate. With the updated code, how do I use PHPUnit to make sure `doSomething` was called when there were 3 items in an array, and not 2 or 4?

Comment: Just try this hardcoded to see how the mock behaves.
If there are 2 or 4 items in the array, the test I posted will fail, because `doSomething` will only work if `array(1, 2, 3)` is passed as parameter 0 - with this array with exactly three entries. So your updated code won't work, because you don't pass the buffer to `doSomething`. In this case you need to define a getter for buffer, get the buffer after execution and assert it against the expected result.
Maybe this will help you o understand mocking:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-about-mocking-with-phpunit--net-27252